# After insert trigger not giving desired result

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-10

I have a trigger on a table called pohead

```
CREATE TRIGGER poautorelease
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE 
  ON public.pohead
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public._poautorelease();
```

which fires the function

```
BEGIN
 IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND NEW.pohead_printed = TRUE) 
 OR (TG_OP = 'INSERT' AND NEW.pohead_printed = TRUE) THEN
   PERFORM releasepurchaseorder(NEW.pohead_id);
 END IF;
 RETURN NEW;
END
```

It seems that on an `UPDATE` the function `releasepurchaseorder()` is performed and on the `INSERT` it is not.
Am I doing anything wrong in code? Or do I need to look elsewhere for the problem.

I have seen some post detailing a `FOR EACH ROW`. but there is only ever one row per update or insert. I think I may be using the `NEW` variable incorrectly.

The other possibility that I might consider if the code is correct is perhaps they disable triggers before they insert? I don't know if this is possible but I assume it must be.

Comment: I would appreciate feedback on the downvote. This is a legitimate problem for me and I am at the end of my knowledge. I would be happy to clarify if I have been unspecific but the downvote makes my post look invalid to anyone who might help me

Comment: The check for `tg_op` seems unnecessary to begin with because nothing else than `insert` or `update` can be there based on the the trigger definition. So `if new.pohead_printed then ... end if;` should be enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I create a tattle-tale function, it works for me on both insert and update.

```
create function releasepurchaseorder(int) returns void language plpgsql as $$ 
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'asfdasfda'; 
END;
$$;
```

Provided of course that pohead_printed is in fact true.

So if you think there really is a problem, then please describe how you decided it is not firing, and show a **full** reproduction case (including the complete definition of the table, and of both functions).  Of course you can simplify both the table and the functions, but verify the simplified versions still exhibit the behavior you are describing.

Comment: my question was more to determine if there is something wrong with the code I posted. I cannot post anything else because I don't have access to it. This basically confirms what I was already thinking. Either A: they disable triggers on Insert Or B: some other mechanic is at play that I don't understand.